# Repeated measures ANOVA Error: contrasts only apply to factors

Tags: r, anova

I'm working as a TA for an intro statistics course and am trying to create a practice question for a repeated measures ANOVA using R. When calling the `car::Anova()` function, I run into the following error:

`` Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (is.ordered(idata[, i])) icontrasts[2] else icontrasts[1]) : contrasts apply only to factors ``

traceback:

```
6.stop("contrasts apply only to factors")
5.`contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (is.ordered(idata[, i])) icontrasts[2] else icontrasts[1])
4.Anova.III.mlm(mod, SSPE, error.df, idata, idesign, icontrasts, imatrix, test, ...)
3.Anova.II.mlm(mod, SSPE, error.df, idata, idesign, icontrasts, imatrix, test.statistic, ...)
2.Anova.mlm(lmaov, idata = idata, idesign = ~Time)
1.Anova(lmaov, idata = idata, idesign = ~Time)
```

I've found a similar problem on Stackoverflow, but that had to do with the factor having only 1 level or NA's in the data, which both are not the case for my problem. I've also tried changing the `Time` variable in the `idata` tibble to an ordered factor, but that did not help either. The `Time` variable in the `idata` tibble is definately of the factor variable type. The data I use is the `BodyWeight` data sourced from the `nlme` package.

my data:

`> as.matrix(data)` returns the following:

```
       1   8  15  22  29  36  43  44  50  57  64
[1,] 240 250 255 260 262 258 266 266 265 272 278
[2,] 225 230 230 232 240 240 243 244 238 247 245
[3,] 245 250 250 255 262 265 267 267 264 268 269
[4,] 260 255 255 265 265 268 270 272 274 273 275
[5,] 255 260 255 270 270 273 274 273 276 278 280
[6,] 260 265 270 275 275 277 278 278 284 279 281
[7,] 275 275 260 270 273 274 276 271 282 281 284
[8,] 245 255 260 268 270 265 265 267 273 274 278
```

`> idata` returns the following:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 1
   Time 
   <fct>
 1 1    
 2 8    
 3 15   
 4 22   
 5 29   
 6 36   
 7 43   
 8 44   
 9 50   
10 57   
11 64
```

My code:

```
library(nlme)
library(car)
library(tidyverse)
data <- BodyWeight %>% 
  #mutate(Time = as.factor(Time)) %>% 
  filter(Diet == 1) %>% ##keep it simple
  pivot_wider(names_from = Time, values_from = weight) %>% #move to wide format, particpants x timepoints
  select(-Diet, -Rat) ##Removing unnecessary columns

time <- BodyWeight %>% 
  pull(Time) %>% 
  as.factor() %>% 
  unique() #%>% ordered()

#time <- factor(time, levels=rev(levels(time)))

idata <- tibble(Time = time)

lmaov <- lm(as.matrix(data)~1)
test <- Anova(lmaov,idata=idata,idesign=~Time)
summary(test, multivariate = FALSE)
```

Session Info:

```
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7     purrr_0.3.4    
 [5] readr_2.0.1     tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.4    ggplot2_3.3.5  
 [9] tidyverse_1.3.1 car_3.0-11      carData_3.0-4   nlme_3.1-153   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fs_1.5.0             lubridate_1.7.10     httr_1.4.2          
 [4] tools_4.0.1          backports_1.2.1      utf8_1.2.2          
 [7] R6_2.5.1             rpart_4.1-15         DBI_1.1.1           
[10] colorspace_2.0-2     nnet_7.3-14          withr_2.4.2         
[13] tidyselect_1.1.1     curl_4.3.2           compiler_4.0.1      
[16] cli_3.0.1            rvest_1.0.1          xml2_1.3.2          
[19] scales_1.1.1         digest_0.6.27        foreign_0.8-80      
[22] rmarkdown_2.10       rio_0.5.27           pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[25] htmltools_0.5.2      parallelly_1.28.1    dbplyr_2.1.1        
[28] fastmap_1.1.0        rlang_0.4.11         readxl_1.3.1        
[31] rstudioapi_0.13      generics_0.1.0       jsonlite_1.7.2      
[34] ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 zip_2.2.0            magrittr_2.0.1      
[37] Matrix_1.2-18        Rcpp_1.0.7           munsell_0.5.0       
[40] fansi_0.5.0          abind_1.4-5          lifecycle_1.0.0     
[43] stringi_1.7.4        pROC_1.18.0          yaml_2.2.1          
[46] MASS_7.3-54          plyr_1.8.6           recipes_0.1.17      
[49] grid_4.0.1           parallel_4.0.1       listenv_0.8.0       
[52] crayon_1.4.1         lattice_0.20-41      haven_2.4.3         
[55] splines_4.0.1        hms_1.1.0            knitr_1.34          
[58] pillar_1.6.2         corpcor_1.6.9        future.apply_1.8.1  
[61] reshape2_1.4.4       codetools_0.2-16     stats4_4.0.1        
[64] reprex_2.0.1         glue_1.4.2           evaluate_0.14       
[67] data.table_1.14.0    modelr_0.1.8         vctrs_0.3.8         
[70] tzdb_0.1.2           foreach_1.5.1        cellranger_1.1.0    
[73] gtable_0.3.0         future_1.22.1        assertthat_0.2.1    
[76] xfun_0.25            gower_0.2.2          openxlsx_4.2.4      
[79] prodlim_2019.11.13   broom_0.7.9          rstatix_0.7.0       
[82] class_7.3-17         survival_3.2-13      timeDate_3043.102   
[85] Hotelling_1.0-8      iterators_1.0.13     lava_1.6.10         
[88] globals_0.14.0       ellipsis_0.3.2       caret_6.0-90        
[91] ipred_0.9-12
```

Thanks! Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: What does `data` look like? I get an error when I run your code.

Comment: @cazman `BodyWeight` is data sourced from the `nlme` package, it runs fine for me

Comment: @cazman I edited the post to provide prints of the data.

Comment: @TrainingPizza Do you mean you can't reproduce the error? Or that the code up until the ```car::Anova()``` runs fine?

Comment: @Bart Kramer I get the error, I was just confirming the data is fine. Have you tried running it with `idata` as a `data.frame` instead of a `tibble`? `tibble`'s don't always work well with functions outside of the `tidyverse`. It also seems a bit more direct to keep the data in long format after filtering for diet, converting Time/Rat to factor and using `aov(formula = weight ~ Time + Error(Rat), data = dat)`

Comment: @TrainingPizza using data.frame() fixed it! I want to do the RM ANOVA the way showed in my code because it follows the book we're using for the course.

Comment: Ok, glad it's resolved at least.

Comment: @TrainingPizza Interesting. I get an undefined columns selected from the `pivot_wider` function. But I agree with keeping it in the long format.

Answer (score 0):

@TrainingPizza found the solution!

Appearantly for this case `tibble(Time = time)` doesnt work well with `car::Anova()`. using `data.frame(Time = time)` fixed the problem.